# Changing body background when hovering over a link

Tags: html, css

I would like to set up my page so that when the user hovers over a link in a div, the color of the body background is changed, but only while hovering. This is the css

```
body {
  background-color: black;
}

a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
  color: white;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Comment: can you use javascript? what youre asking for is not possible with just css alone, as far as I know

Comment: I have a basic grasp on javascript, I am open to any ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is actually not possible with CSS as you are asking if there is a **parent selector** BUT we can use some workarounds.

Here is an idea where I use a pseudo element from the `a` that I make it to cover the whole body and it behaves as the background of the body:

```css
a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:before {
  content: "";
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #000;
  z-index: -1;
  pointer-events:none;
}

a:hover::before {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: It's not possible to do so in pure CSS yet, however...

---

Long answer:
There's a pseudoclass `:has()` that can select element, that has specific properties. In your case it would be something like this: `body:has(div a:hover)`.

Unfortunatelly, it has [no support](https://caniuse.com/#search=%3Ahas) yet.

---

However it's [possible](https://jsfiddle.net/eqgLbxjh/) to do so using HTML `<input>` and `<label>` elements except you can't change `background-color` of `<body>` element, because `<body>` start tag is generated automatically by the browser before any element that should be inside it [no matter where in code it's actually written](https://jsfiddle.net/eqgLbxjh/2/).

HTML:

```
<body>
    <input id="magic" type="checkbox">
    <div>
        <label for="magic"><a href="#">Link</a></label>
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
html, body, div {
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
#magic:hover + div {
    background: red;
}
input {
    position: fixed;
    left: -100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not very pretty, but you can use the `:before` pseudo-element on `body`

```
<a class="change-bg" href="">link 1</a>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #fff;
}

a.change-bg:hover:before {
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #000;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bjsvhze8/13/