# CSS change Body Style Based on Sub-Element's class

Tags: css

Using CSS alone, is it possible for a deeply subordinate html element's class, to effect the style of the document.body element.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <div class="someStatus"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

When this deeply embedded div's class changes, I'd like to change the background color of the document.body element (as an example).

I know how to do this with JavaScript. However, is it possible using CSS exclusively?

Comment: for background only, yes we can do some trick ... but for more general CSS, it's impossible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39374918/3597276

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48996952/changing-body-background-when-hovering-over-a-link/48997054#48997054